# Head First Design Pattern: When to not use Interface (specifically in Java 'interface')

Tags: java, design-patterns

I have *just* started reading the book, and in the **Strategy pattern** they *discouraged the use of **interface whose role is just to enforce** an implementation of a single method on the subclasses*.

However, upon the next chapter: **Observer Pattern**, they did just that. Wherein, *they used a Display interface with a display method to be implemented by the concrete observers*.

My question is: **in the end is it really okay to use interfaces like that? If not, is there a better method on how to do this?**

Comment: But the ***implementation*** (that is how and where display renders) is not enforced by the interface.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I'm sorry, can you expound your answer as I did not get it

Comment: Every interface requires an implementation to implement some method. The advice you are missing was directed at the **how**. Not the **what**.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Yes okay, I think now know what you are hinting at. I don't know if I have phrased the question wrong. But what I'm essentially asking is that, according to the book, use of interface like that would create **maintenance nightmares** but they used it as that on the next design pattern.

Comment: Or is that because they anticipated that there would be no *code reuse* across other implementation?

Comment: Surely there's a reason they discouraged it for strategy. That's important but not in your question. Can you explain?

Comment: @Fuhrmanator I have phrased the situation and question wrong, but corrected it now. Thank you all for reaching out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the strategy pattern example, we have many Duck subclasses, but only a few different ways of flying and quacking, so we use composition instead of inheritance for giving Duck subclasses flying and quacking behaviour.

The "maintenance nightmare" they mention would be if a change to flying or quacking had to be repeated in many Duck subclasses, instead of just in one concrete strategy implementation.

In the case of an Observer, each Observer implementation has its own reasons for wanting to be notified, so there isn't repeated code to be extracted.

Of course the strategy pattern does use interfaces, one each for quacking and flying.

Comment: So, the key point is that, it is alright to use interface to make sure that the subclass would have an implementation of that specific method, as long as there would be **no code reuse** across different class. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, that's what they are suggesting. Sometimes you might do the code reuse in a parent class, but in this case we have two things (flying and quacking) which very orthogonally, so you can't have that code in a parent class (you could in a language with multiple inheritance of implementations).